# chrome extension shouldn't load (or block) scripts of the DOM

Tags: dom, google-chrome, scripting, google-chrome-extension, block

is it possible to block all  of a website before they are loaded?

I can remove all  after the DOM is done but events declared with these scripts are still happening which I would like to prevent.

Thanks!

Comment: "block all of a website" - don't visit it? I'm sorry, but you're not quite clear on what you want to do here, and why, and what you want to prevent happening.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. there are ads and "onmouseover" etc events which I would like to prevent. I know, I could use adblock for the ads. but there are onmouseover-eventsfor the navigation which drive me nuts. I would like to block them (if possible all scripts of this website) and use a user-css for that :)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that with a Chrome extension until the DOM has fully loaded, because of how Chrome works, and how Chrome user security works... but I could of course be totally wrong. =)

Comment: Can you give examples of what exactly are you trying to block? Techniques are very different depending on what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block a site's javascript wholesale, you can do that without any extensions. Go to `Preferences -> Under the hood -> Content settings -> Javascript -> Manage exceptions`. From there you can add a rule to block the site from running javascript.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to give this extension to my friends, so it would be easier if the scripts are blocked through the extension. 

May be I look into this "NotScripts" extension and try to understand how it blocks js ;)